# Laravel Service layer: passing HTTP request from controller to service

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, service

I am developing a Laravel application and using a Service layer pattern to isolate business logic. What I come across in all tutors/articles is passing the HTTP request object from the controller directly into the service. To me, it goes against the principle of a service being an API-independent piece of code that has a single responsibility for a certain functionality. Imagine I would like to call the service from the command line or from an event handler, I would then have to construct an HTTP Request object to pass to the controller.

Same goes for validation: as far as I understand, the validator would on failure either redirect the user back (which may have no sense in the case of command line or event handler) or return an HTTP error.

On the other hand, with a lot of form fields, there should be some structure to pass the data in, and the form itself already gives such structure.

What are best practices regarding this?